# Selenium can't find html element injected by javascript

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am accessing a page with a javascript challenge on it (https://www.bstn.com). This challenge does it's magic and then presents a checkbox that the user should click to complete the challenge.

I want to automate clicking this checkbox, but that's where my issue presents. This checkbox element doesn't exist in the page source, as it gets loaded by the executed javascript. So when I command selenium to find the checkbox element and click it, it's unable to find it as selenium only searches in the page source.

How can I possibly click this checkbox automatically?